# Weird behavior with CTRL-G

Tags: vim

I am using gvim from the Vim 7.3 installation on Windows 7 (x86).

When I type <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd> to get a line count of the current file, I see `:browse confirm saveas` displayed at the bottom of the screen, a dialog window flashes, and there are several beeps.

I have disabled my custom **_vimrc** file, and the behavior persists.

Also: when trying to debug a problem like this, what are some standard steps to follow?  For example, is there a "safe mode" in Vim?

My mappings:

[image]

Comment: So you're using `vim`, not `gvim`? Can you reproduce problem in both `vim` and `gvim`? "Safe mode" is usually `vim -u NONE`, which disables loading of configuration files. Stardard steps to debug shortcut issues is to run commands like `:map <shortcut>` and read their output.

Comment: I am using gvim, sorry for not making that clear, fixed the question.  I just tried `gvim -u NONE`, but got the same behavior.  (The output from `:map` command is only a few lines long, though.)

Comment: If you type `<c-v><c.g>` in insert mode after starting `gvim` as `gvim -u NONE`, what do you see?

Comment: Assuming by `<c.g>` you mean CTRL-G, I get the same behavior.  Also, some garbage characters are inserted.

Comment: Yes, I meant `<c-g>`. What garbase characters (it might give some hints)? It looks like some other program intercepts `<c-g>` and handles it in a strange way.

Comment: Following characters inserted when <c-v><c-g> typed in input mode:  `^\á`

Comment: Sorry, don't know what it means, you might have some non-english language input method interfering.

Comment: +1 OK, thanks just the same, especially for the safe mode start-up.

Comment: For anyone finding this question, I was seeing similar weird behaviour with CTRL-G in MingW vim (from Git for Windows). It turned out my terminal (console-Z) was capturing CTRL-G as a "Group All" command. Remapped that and vim's CTRL-G now works.